# Which are some planes shaped like an inverted wing?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, wing, airfoil, fuselage

To understand my question better, let's consider the priciple behind the lift generated by the wing - The upper surface of the air-foil is curved to deflect the air downwards using the Coanda effect. According to Newton's 3rd Law, an equal reaction is produced by the downwards deflection of air in the form of lift.

[image: Borrowed from *simhq.com*]

So here's my question - **Why aren't some planes designed to look like a massive cross-section of a wing from the side?** e.g. A Cessna C172 looks like an inverted wing (with the curved side on the bottom, which might create 'inverse lift' by pulling it down. From that aspect, is the Cirrus SR22 and the Cessna TTx more lift-friendly? Their upper part of the fuselage is relatively more curved than their lower part when viewed from the side. Or am I making a mistake - is it due to high-wing low-wing design philosophies?

[image: Borrowed from *flyawaysimulation.com*]
[image: Borrowed from *aircraftbluebooks.com*]

Comment: 1. The airfoil is generally not constant over the span, 2. "*The upper surface of the air-foil is curved to increase the distance of air traveling above the wing*", not to increase distance, but to deflect air downward without adding too much drag (there are airfoils with [both sides curved or symetrical](http://www.waybuilder.net/free-ed/Resources/15-Transportation/Aviation/pics/Princi8.jpg)).

Comment: @mins: Thank you for clarifying - I apologise for my flawed understanding of lift generated by an air-foil - I have edited the question to better define lift, but could you tell me why there are so many varied theories as to how a wing / air-foil creates lift? Thanks! : )

Comment: There is only one real theory. The Navier-Stokes equations. And then many more or less simplified or phenomenological descriptions. Many of them oversimpkified or incorrect.

Comment: @VladimirF So how have these theories (like Bernoulli's Priciple theory, Downwash, Impact Lift, etc.) popup?

Comment: Bernoulli's equestion is directly derived from the N.-S. equations under certain simplification assumptions. The others are phenomenological descriptions.

Comment: The Bernoulli theory of lift is also incorrect as it relies on a false assumption. Basically the Bernoulli theory says that two adjacent particles that separate (one to travel over the top and one to travel along the bottom) will meet up at the trailing edge and so the one which traveled along the curved path must go faster.  This is false the particles do not meet up at the trailing edge in fact the upper surface particles reach the trailing edge long before the lower surface particles. There are some very nice videos of wind tunnel tests showing this.

Comment: I dispute the premise of the question. When I look at the two aircraft illustrations, I see a more-or-less flat underside, with the upper surface having a bulge at the front -- just like the aerofoil. I appreciate that there is some bulge on the underside, but it's pretty insignificant compared to the cockpit bubble.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - I welcome your argument - The Cessna TTx in the illustration does have a slightly curved under-side, but still is not as pronounced as the C172's under-side, which looks strikingly similar to the airfoil diagram (also in question) flipped about its horizontal axis. Also the top-side of the TTx has an overall curve to it, compared to the distinct 'hump' of the C172. I apologise as I cannot explain this better without a diagram.

Comment: @AnandS I agree if you remove the cockpit. But that seems too big an "if", to me.

Comment: @DavidRicherby But since the C172's cockpit abruptly rises up from the topside, it doesn't let air flow as smoothly as the TTx does, which starts curving right behind the prop, and ends right in front of the tail... Or does it?

Comment: @DJ319 No, you are wrong. The Bernoulli equation does not assume any such thing. Only certain wrong explanations of lift say that. The Bernouli equation is not 100% accurate, but works fairly well when viscous losses are small. And they are small enough normally.

Comment: The Cessna photo appears to have the standard drooped wingtip, it may give a misleading impression of the actual wing profile

Comment: @VladimirF Not the Bernoulli equation the Bernoulli theory of lift. Viscous forces are pretty large on aircraft and account for a large portion of the drag.

Comment: @DJ319  The theory of lift which explains the lift using the Bernoulli equation does not need any meeting of particles at the trailing edge. It simply does not. It needs faster air at the suction side and the air IS indeed faster there. It is even faster than the naive picture of equal times of flight. The Bernoulli equation works very well for basic lift calculation. And the viscous force do account for the skin friction drag (which may or may not be of the same magnitude of the form drag) but it plays very little role for the lift. Only for the drag.

Comment: @VladimirF It would seem we were taught different definitions of the Bernoulli theory of lift. This is what I am referring to https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/wrong1.html 
I see the article calls it equal transit theory. So perhaps that is where my confusion is but I recall being taught this as the Bernoulli theory of lift when I did Fluid dynamics

Comment: @DJ319 Even the page you are referring to does NOT call this incorrect description *"Bernoulli theory of lift"*. And correctly, because this isn't any such thing. Look here https://owlcation.com/stem/Aerodynamics-The-Theory-of-Lift under *"Correct Theories of Lift: Bernoulli and Newton"*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your intuitive feeling that the fuselage could be used to create additional lift is correct. Indeed, some aircraft are specifically shaped such that fuselage could provide substantial lift (and that's excluding any 'flying wing' design where fuselage is completely blended with the wing).

However, these are generally supersonic fighter aircraft. At supersonic speeds, even the 'normal' tubular fuselage will create significant lift, given a decent angle of attack. Moreover, the engine air intakes, if properly designed, will create even more lift.

In GA aircraft, on the other hand, the effect must be negligible, and structural considerations (yes, including high/low wing) are much more important.

The primary aerodynamic consideration for the fuselage is, generally, minimising its drag and reducing interference with other parts, primarily the wing. In this regard, by the way, C172 (or any high-wing aircraft) is more 'lift-friendly'. High-wing design has less negative wing/fuselage interference; in fact, it can be even positive. In simple terms, the part of the wing above the fuselage still creates lift, and probably more of it than the whole fuselage (although I have no numbers at hand).

I also must duly note that the principle of lift generation has little to do with the geometric length of the upper and lower surfaces. It is a popular misconception. The air indeed moves faster over the upper surface, but this is due to entirely different reasons. There are several good explanations of lift on this site.

Comment: Very thorough and simple at the same time - great answer! So the difference in the fuselage shape of a C172 and the SR22 is due to low-wing, high-wing design factors only?

Comment: @AnandS, it's hard to prove the 'only' clause without getting into the heads of the designers. But yes, I'd say primarily that. For SR22 at least, even just the aesthetic appeal could be a factor.

Comment: @AnandS The main reason the bottom of the plane angles upward towards the tail is to avoid tailstrikes on takeoff and landing. The greater the angle between the ground and the bottom of the tail the more the plane can rotate with the wheels still on the ground.

Comment: A flying wing has _no_ fuselage at all.  An aircraft where the fuselage blends smoothly with the wing, like the F-15, is a [blended wing-body](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blended_wing_body) aircraft.